# Tool for randomized signatures

Tags: email, utilities

Is there a tool for randomizing signatures (for 10.8/.9)?

I.e. I'd like to maintain a list a signatures (e.g. with different quotes, etc) and swap them randomly or every such-and-such minutes.

I'm using different email apps for different accounts so something that would simply change the signature text file that's then loaded in to Thunderbird, Mail, etc. would be great.

Answer (score 1):

About the only luck I've had, other than writing scripts myself, is using [SignatureProfiler](http://littleknownsoftware.com/sigpro/).  Note that it's not free ($12).

It's mostly overkill for what I need, which is just the random signatures, so I've implemented a few little scripts to get this working on my own machine - [Random Signatures for OSX](http://jamesalday.com/2014/03/27/random-quote-signatures-for-osx-mail.html)

Note, however, that something seems to have changed in 10.10 that is now preventing Mail from updating the signature when the signature file itself is updated (until I manually trigger it, or restart mail).  They must have some kind of caching in mail now for the sig files so that it's not read in every time.

Comment: ..then there's http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7137/signature-randomizer

Comment: That one's a bit old - don't happen to have a PPC Mac anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Try '**ThunderWiz**' on the *Mac App Store* https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/thunderwiz/id1350413811?ls=1&mt=12
(also cheaper than the app mentioned above)

Comment: Please explain why thais is good. An answer should be more than a link (or cut and paste from another site)